# Confusion regarding Double quote in a CSV file

Tags: csv

```
""Ford" 1997"
```

Would it be considered as a valid field in CSV file?
Let's say the whole record is:

```
""Ford" 1997",E350,"Luxurious car"
```

Or may be:

```
""Ford",1997,"Luxurious car"
```

Would it be a valid record?

Comment: I'm happy to be corrected but I do not believe there is a definitive standard for CSV files. The more double quotes and weird unbalanced stuff you put in there the less likely it is to be compatible.

Comment: i found this wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and there are couple of standards.

Answer (score 0):

Um. I am sure there is no 'standard' for csv.  I think that it is a crap shoot to say what is valid what is not.  It largely depends where the data is going (regardless of standard).  If excel accepts it and that is the way it is, then great.  If whatever other target does not accept it - that that is the way it is.

However, what you are dealing with is a quote-enclosed comma separated value.

If we are looking at comma only your record is fine (but potential for datatype error exists). 
If we are looking at quote enclosed comma seperated fields  - your record(s) are bad.

Comment: according to this wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and RCF 4180 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) we can have comma or space inside a double-quoted field. but im confused about double quote inside a double quoted field. should it must have a pair of them or a single can exist?

Comment: I commend you on doing your reseear - too many don't.  "A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters"  [wiki]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values  yours has an extra.  What is your target for this data?

Comment: in the same wiki you'll find, field with embedded comma must be quoted. btw, I'm creating a csv to cpp object parser.

Comment: i got my answer. thanks.
i should build my parser according to my need. it has nothing to do with the standard.